# How to enable Directory Browsing on a folder on a Sitecore web site?

Tags: iis

I would like to allow directory browsing and anonymous access for a specific folder in Sitecore, but I can't find out how.

Does anyone have a clue about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add your directory path to `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` settings:

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="...|/your-directory-path" />
```

and add a `web.config` file inside that directory with content:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to by pass Sitecore all together and load up some static HTML for example, add your path on the end of this pipe separated setting in the Web.config or in Sitecore.config in later versions of Sitecore.

Sitecore will then ignore the path an IIS should take effect.

```
 <setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value=".........|/YourPath" />
```